# xcode swift admob not showing live ads on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, admob, ios-simulator, ads

I have implemented AdMob before on Android apps and unless I specified
a test ad the Android Simulator would show up live ads.

> @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

```
//Display Ads
self.bannerView.adUnitID = "mypubid"
self.bannerView.rootViewController = self
var request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
self.bannerView.loadRequest(request)
```

I dont use any .test devices GAD_SIMULATOR, so it shouldnt display 
any test ads, but what I see after the app loads is this test banner:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXyPF.png

I have set up a Bridging Header and that -ObjC variable.
I dont know why it is displaying test ads when I havent 
specified any test devices.

Am I doing anything wrong? Or the ios admob sdk is different from android's
and it doesnt display live ads on simulator.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of the iOS SDK will always show test ads on the simulator. You don't need to manually add a test device, since anyone using the simulator is guaranteed to be testing.

Comment: Hi,
So If I were to run the app on a real device it would show up Live Ads?

Comment: If you don't add any test devices, then yes, you will see live ads when running on a hardware device. Bear in mind, though, that developing and testing using live ads is a violation of AdMob policy and could lead to suspension of your account.

Comment: I am well aware of that, I am very careful about my admob account. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Is there a way to show live ads on the Simulator for the purpose of preparing the screen capture for publishing the app? Apple rejects the app if the screen capture shows "test", "beta" etc.

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can capture the screens of hardware devices: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/capture_screenshots_from_device.html