# Why is my ad not showing when I run the test on the IOS simulator?

Tags: swift, xcode, admob, banner

I hooked up my app with adMob. When I run the tests on the ios simulator no test ad appears. Also my app is now slower and glitchier. What is wrong? This is in my `viewDidLoad` function

```
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-4520288405399190/1979194331"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(request)
```

Comment: Did you figure this out already? Is that adUnitID your own? You should use Google Admob's sample ad unit ids when testing: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#sample_ad_units

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816630/xcode-swift-admob-not-showing-live-ads-on-simulator

Comment: @GabrielPires The sample ad unit ID works just not mine. Here is the error: `<Google> Invalid Request. Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?`. I think I will talk to Google tomorrow and see what the problem is

Comment: I get same error, no idea why